# ArrayList Natural Ordering

Tags: android, sqlite, collections, sorting, comparable

I have a application using a sqlite DB which is put into an ArrayList. I am trying to get the entries to show in alphabetical or from what I understand "natural ordering". I have implemented comparable and have added my collections.sort statement but the array list remains in non alphabetical or natural order. please advise

```
public class LoginList extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {

private ListView loginList;
private Button webLogin;
private ListAdapter loginListAdapter;
private ArrayList<LoginDetails> loginArrayList;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);

    loginList = (ListView)
    findViewById(R.id.loginlist);
    loginList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    webLogin = (Button)
    findViewById(R.id.button3);
    webLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    loginArrayList = new ArrayList<xxxxxxxx>();
    loginListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    loginList.setAdapter(LAdapter);
    Collections.sort(AList );

    }

@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    Intent webLoginIntent = new Intent (this, LoginPlusActivity.class);
    startActivity(webLoginIntent);

}

public List<String> populateList (){

    List<String> webNameList = new ArrayList<String>();


    dataStore openHelperClass = new dataStore (this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase("xxxxxxxx");

    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){

    String sName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE));
    String wUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS));
    String uName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME));
    String pWord = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD));

    LoginDetails lpDetails = new LoginDetails();

        lpDetails.setsName(sName);
        lpDetails.setwUrl(wUrl);
        lpDetails.setuName(uName);
        lpDetails.setpWord(pWord);

        loginArrayList.add(lpDetails);
        webNameList.add(sName); 
}
sqliteDatabase.close();
return webNameList;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
loginListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
loginList.setAdapter(loginListAdapter);
    }

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0 , View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected ID :" + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent updateDeleteLoginInfo = new Intent (this, UpdateDeleteLoginList.class);

    LoginDetails clickedObject = loginArrayList.get(arg2);

        Bundle loginBundle = new Bundle();
    loginBundle.putString("clickedWebSite",clickedObject.getsName());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedWebAddress",clickedObject.getwUrl());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedUserName",clickedObject.getuName());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedPassWord",clickedObject.getpWord());  

    updateDeleteLoginInfo.putExtras(loginBundle);   
    startActivity(updateDeleteLoginInfo);
}
    }
```

SQLite:

```
 String sqlDataStore = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME_XXXXXXXXX + " ("+ BaseColumns._ID + "integer primary key autoincrement "

                    + COLUMN_NAME_XXXX + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_XXXXXXX + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_XXXXXXXX + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_XXXXXXXX + " text not null);"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
  Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

With this:

```
  Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, null, null, null, null, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE, null);
```

To order your results by the COLUMN_NAME_SITE.

This way, your cursor will be preordered when you have done the query and you don't need a comparable interface.

Comment: Davies answer was correct but an additional "null" was needed before Colunm_name..." without the null the "Column_name..." would be under HAVING and not ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just edit the WHERE clause in your sqlite query.
You will want to add something like this

```
ORDER BY TITLE COLLATE NOCASE ASC
```

Note "TITLE" is whatever column you want to sort on.

This will place everything in ABC order while ignoring case.
Resulting in AaBcD instead of ABDac

Using SQLite you won't need to mess with comparing at all :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from TABLENAME_HERE order by COLUMN_NAME_HERE", null);
```

Replace instead of

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```